# Counting number of lines starting with `File: ` in a log file

Tags: bash

I want to count the number of lines starting with `File:`  in a log file.

But the following are giving an incorrect result.

```
nf=$( sed '/^File: /p' $logfl | wc -l )
nf=$( awk '/^File: / {nf++} END {print nf}' $logfl )
```

Here is the log file.

```
%rec: comint
Logtrk: /home/hagbard/Opstk/bin/gungadin-1.0/logs
Lognam: comint-18694-T07:59:17.912436326.rec
Ptrn: FN
File: ./comint.rc
File: ./comseq.rc
nrp: 55
ndk: 55  ;  wdk: 55
ndk: 55
```

Comment: Your awk version should work - provided the trailing character is really a space (not a tab, for example). For the sed version, you'd need `sed -n` to turn off default printing. You should of course quote the expansion `"$logfl"`.

Comment: You are right about needed the `-n` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do:

```
grep -c '^File: ' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk`

```
awk '/^File:  / {n++} END {print n}' logfile
```

Or `grep`

```
grep -c '^File: ' logfile
```